# Why did ICC decide to go with Champions Trophy 2017?

Tags: cricket, icc

[Wikpedia indicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_Champions_Trophy) that in 2013, the ICC announced that the [2013 Champions Trophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_ICC_Champions_Trophy), 
would be their final one.

However, Wikipedia states that

> However, in January 2014, that decision was reversed, with the ICC
>   confirming that the 2017 Champions Trophy tournament would take place
>   and the proposed Test Championship was cancelled.

Has any motivation been provided for this reversal?

Comment: Clearly, yes it did change its decision. What sort of answer are you looking for to this question?

Comment: @PhilipKendall i want to know the reason which made them change their decision if possible.

Comment: The decision to stop this competition was also mentioned in this older questions: [Does ICC intend to stop the ICC Champions Trophy?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/2095)

Comment: Because ICC. Is that not enough? Since when do we expect ICC to make up its mind on anything? They keep flip-flopping all the time. Powerplays, DRS, ODI rules, just look at *any* decision the ICC has ever made, and you will notice they would have invariably backtracked or adjusted it within 6 to 12 months.

Comment: @MaskedMan you are right, I am just interested in reason if anyone has any idea about it, that's all i want know.

Comment: @KinjalPatel If you really insist on a "reason", the reason is that the ICC is run by a bunch of clueless incompetent administrators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kinjal The motivation arose from the vast success of the 2013 Champions Trophy - which is no surprise given India's success. They had previously planned to begin their proposed ICC World Test Championship instead from 2014. However after the dramatic crowd and TV viewers, they chose to retain it - why it took them 3 more years to finalise the Test Championship is due to issues regarding broadcasting and sponsorship. A couple of statements from Haroon Lorgat, then ICC Chief Executive, on the matter:

http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci-icc/content/story/540505.html
http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci-icc/content/story/536018.html
http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci-icc/content/story/561563.html

Comment: Do you have any references you can use to back up this answer - a quote from someone at the ICC would be wonderful?

Comment: "The Champions Trophy was originally meant to be scrapped after the 2013 edition, but the huge commercial success of that year's tournament in England led to it being retained, at the expense of the World Test Championship that had been scheduled for 2017." A couple of sources and quality reads: http://www.espncricinfo.com/wisdenalmanack/content/story/780731.html, http://www.espncricinfo.com/story/_/id/16444064/future-icc-champions-trophy-back-doubt.

Comment: Please edit the appropriate quotes into your answer rather than leaving them as comments. However, neither of those seem particularly strong to me - the quote you give is from a journalist, not from anyone at the ICC.

Comment: @Philip Edits made